# open and close button in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a button and I can open it but I just don't know how close it; can you help me with that?

And another thing:
how can I remove border when the button is clicked?

```js
document.getElementById("arrowbtn1").onclick = arrow1;


function arrow1() {
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "You can invite up to 2 additional users on the<br>\
Free plan.There is no limit on team members for <br>\
the Premium plan.";
  document.getElementById("span1").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
  document.getElementById("span1").style.fontWeight = "bold";
  document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
  document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.marginTop = "5px";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="arrowbtn1"> 
  <span id="span1">How many team members can I invite?</span>
  <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage1"class="arrowimage">
</button>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "close it" You want to reverse the transform and hide the p?

Comment: Define "close it" and show us your attempts so far.

Comment: if you can deploy a text when clicking on a button you can remove the text by the same way... isn't it. same answer for the second question...

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a ***class*** that displays the element as ***none*** on the ***`P`*** element. Place the text you wish to show directly in the HTML, rather than using innerHTML and JS to place the text in the ***`p`*** element. Use CSS for the arrows as well. Then you can use a conditional to check if the class that hides the element is present using `el.classlist.contains('displayNone')` if this is true, then ***toggle/add/remove*** *classes* that display the proper content using ***CSS***.

```js
document.getElementById("arrowbtn1").onclick = arrow1;

let span1 = document.getElementById("span1");
let arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow");
let p1 = document.getElementById("p1");

function arrow1() {
  span1.style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
  if (p1.classList.contains("displayNone")) {    
    span1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    p1.classList.toggle("displayNone")
    arrow.classList.remove("down");
    arrow.classList.add("up");
  } else {     
    span1.style.fontWeight = "400";
    p1.classList.toggle("displayNone")
    arrow.classList.remove("up");
    arrow.classList.add("down");
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.up {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="arrowbtn1"> 
  <span id="span1">How many team members can I invite?</span>     <span class="arrow down"></span>
  
</button>
<p id="p1" class="displayNone">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</p>
```